# Protractor can not find allert

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have situation. When i click "Update" button on my web-application - alert with successful message is visible. But protractor can not find it. Code html:

```
<div class="toast ng-scope toast-success" ng-mouseout="restartTimer(toaster)" ng-mouseover="stopTimer(toaster)" ng-click="click(toaster)" ng-class="toaster.type" ng-repeat="toaster in toasters" style="">
<!-- ngIf: toaster.showCloseButton -->
<div class="ng-binding toast-title" ng-class="config.title"/>
<div class="toast-message" on="toaster.bodyOutputType" ng-switch="" ng-class="config.message">
<!-- ngSwitchWhen: trustedHtml -->
<!-- ngSwitchWhen: template -->
<!-- ngSwitchWhen: templateWithData -->
<!-- ngSwitchWhen: directive -->
<!-- ngSwitchDefault: -->
<div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-switch-default="">The application record has been successfully updated</div>
<!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: toaster in toasters -->
</div>
```

So, protractor can not find it:

```
<div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-switch-default="">The application record has been successfully updated</div>
```

What is a problem?

I use that locator

```
element.all(by.repeater('toaster in toasters'))
```

Comment: what is the exception occurred when you trying??

Comment: Thank you for response!
There is no exception. 
When i try to find element inside ng-repeater ='toaster in toasters' , it returns 0 elements. 
So protractor locate repeator, but it can not locate any element inside it.

But protractor should find 1 element

`<div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-switch-default="">The application record has been successfully updated</div>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ExpectedConditions in your script, it will prevent Protractor from looking for alert before it actually appeared on page. If its not resolved go below option
2. Try by Update and Degrade the toaster versions. it will work.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!

There is strange situation. That alert is present on a lot of pages. And i can locate it with protractor. But on one page i can not do it. I do not know why.

Yes, i tried ExpectedConditions.

I think , that there is some loading on page, And protractor try to find that element only after some loading.

What do you think about it?